# facebook iOS SDK authorization without redirect to safari

Tags: ios, facebook

I need to authorize the access to facebook within the app, because I need to store the cookies where they can be used by the app later. So I want that the autorization takes place in a webview without the need for redirecting to safari. After some research I saw some answers for this problem, which consist of changing the following line:

```
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES];
```

to

```
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];
```

However, this is not working for me. It does not redirect to safari anymore, but does not open the webview either. Am I missing something? The connection with facebook works fine when redirecting to safari, so the SDK should be well installed.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

With the help of breakpoints in the FBDialog.m code, I can see that the method `webViewDidFinishLoad:`is being called, so I assume it is working as expected. However, I also add the line `NSLog(@"view %@",self);` to the end of the `init` method in the FBDialog.m, which produces the text in the console:

`view <FBLoginDialog: 0x4e316f0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x4e321c0>>`

As you can see the width and height of the frame is 0, 0. Could this be the reason for the UIWebView never show up?
A little help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. I was calling the `authorize` method of the facebook object before the `makeKeyAndVisible`method of the window.

Comment: I am having the same problem..I using SDK sample ..`sessionLoginSample ` of that....what changes do i need to make?? to without redirect to safari